# ui bootstrap modal needs two controllers

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create modal window with login form using ui-bootstrap angular module.

I created two controllers but after  that i realized that two controllers to one modal window is too much so i decided two merge it into one. And then i got 3 errors which i can't solve for so long, please help me.

> angular.js:14239 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- LoginModalCtrl
>
> angular.js:14239 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- LoginModalCtrl <- LoginModalCtrl
>
> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- LoginModalCtrl <- LoginModalCtrl <- LoginModalCtrl

I am sure i spelled everything correctly any dependencies.

Code of two controllers which worked for me before putting them together

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f0286abe139a02749d7b4e55d57b3fdd

And finally code of frankenstein i've created from mixing them.

```
app.controller('LoginModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$uibModalInstance', '$uibModal', 'authenticationService', function($scope, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, $location, authenticationService) {
var $ctrl = this;
$ctrl.modalInstance = null;


$ctrl.animationsEnabled = true;

$ctrl.open = function(size, parentSelector) {
    var parentElem = parentSelector ?
        angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.modal-login' + parentSelector)) : undefined;

    $ctrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
        ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-header',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
        templateUrl: 'loginModalContent.html',
        backdropClass: "modal-backdrop",
        size: size,
        backdrop: true,
        appendTo: parentElem,

        resolve: {
            items: function() {
                return $ctrl.items;
            }
        }
    });
};

$ctrl.login = function() {
        //
        authenticationService.login($ctrl.loginData)
            .then(function(data) {

                $uibModalInstance.close();
                $location.url("/");

            }, function(error) {

            });
    };

    $ctrl.cancel = function() {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Make the order of your dependencies same. Which means the array: `['$scope', ... , 'authenticationService']` and `function($scope, ... , authenticationService)` should have the identical order.

Comment: I changed but still got [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider :(

Comment: I additionaly deleted '$uibModalInstance', and now it is opening and seems working but close button on right top corner and login button doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the source of your problem:

```
app.controller('LoginModalCtrl', 
  ['$scope', '$location', '$uibModalInstance', '$uibModal', 'authenticationService', 
  function($scope, $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, $location, authenticationService) {
...
```

All providers must match the order they were injected in. It's much better, cleaner, easier to read when you use suggestions from John Papa's style guide:

```
app.controller('LoginModalCtrl', LoginModalCtrl);

LoginModalCtrl.$inject = [
  '$scope', '$location', 
  '$uibModalInstance', '$uibModal', 
  'authenticationService'
];
function LoginModalCtrl(
  $scope, $location,
  $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, 
  authenticationService
) {
...
}
```

Also, you should not be injecting both `$uibModal` and `$uibModalInstance` in the same controller. That means something is not right (unless you are trying to open a 2nd modal from within the first modal. Not common and considered bad practice).

`$uibModal` is injected into the controller **that opens the modal.**

`$uibModalInstance` is injected into the controller **that is the modal.**

It also looks like you did not specify a controller when you opened the modal:

```
$ctrl.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    ...
    controller: $ctrl.login
    ...
});
```

Comment: Okey so I added $uiModal into navigationCtrl (parent of loginModalCtrl) and pasted there a method which opens a controller, but this sample of code is using uiModalInstance, look:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/294d8e83daeec154633843580aea0401

Comment: No, actually, it's not. It's using a local variable called `$ctrl.modalInstance`. That is not the same thing as the Angular UI provider called `$uibModalInstance`. That variable could have been named anything, like `$ctrl.hereIsAModalInstance`. The provider `$uibModalInstance` refers to the injected provider provided by Angular UI Bootstrap library.

Comment: You are my hero. I've changed everything and now i have open method in Header ctrl (parent) and modal ctrl, look:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7605973c0c626600c648b19e2646f424

and now error is: 

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: uibModalProvider <- uibModal <- HeaderCtrl